# Google + Partner Insert activity

Tags: php, html, api, google-plus

So I have the google + partners program, and I'm using the php library to get the activities but I don't see a POST available for the SDK

```
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/plusPages/v2/people/userId/activities
```

So this works fine:

```
$activities = $plus->activities->get('me', 'public', $optParams);
```

but how do i insert using the api?

Yes, I do have the google+ partners program so I can post

Comment: What happends when you run that are there errors?

Comment: It's about "inserting" not listing data

Comment: You do understand that this is a read only api. You can't post to the Google+ website.   If you are a partner you should contact your account manager they should be able to help you better than stack

Comment: Have you tried with [Google+ Domains API](https://developers.google.com/+/domains/posts/creating)?

Comment: I found [this](https://developers.google.com/partners/reference/rest/v2/userEvents/log) that talks about POST and logging events... don't know if that is helpful at all

Answer (score 1):

There is no insert method defined in the API itself, so there is no way the SDK could allow you to do so.

From API docs in

> https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/?#s/plus/v1/

and

> https://developers.google.com/+/web/api/rest/latest/

We can tell it is a read only API - with just *get*, *list* and *search* methods. So I guess your question has no good answer - apart from: It is not possible.

Comment: There most be a way since... they allow you to insert, if you apply to a partner's form and get accepted

Comment: That would require a different API. Did they send you access to another API and it's docs?

Comment: Yes, but it's just a diffrent URL

Comment: Can you share the API documentation url?